# Kali installation - fclose: no space left on the device

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, disk-usage

I spent a whole day on this and I've tried every method but got no solution. I'm trying to install Kali Linux on my ASUS laptop with 1 TB HDD and 4 GB RAM. After 85 - 88% installation `fclose: no disk space left on device` error message pops up. I've tried guided partitioning (graphical install) in Kali Linux recommended partitioning configuration. I've also tried manual partitioning.

During manual partitioning I've tried increasing and decreasing size of swap partitions and boot partition too, but the same error message pops up during 80 - 90% of installation and the screen goes black. So to find out the exact error, I went for text installation procedure. There I found that the system is saying `fclose: no disk space left on device`. After that make `/home` partition different but got same `fclose: no disk space left on device` error message. I've also done trying making `/home` and `/usr` separate partitioning but got no result again system saying `fclose: no disk space left on device`.

I've literally tried every possible partitioning method from installation guide with recommended and variable partition size method, but I'm unable to get rid of that problem. 
I'm pretty sure that I'm selecting my HDD for partitioning.

I have no other OS installed on my HDD. Has anyone faced this problem before while installing Kali Linux? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: How much of the 1TB is available for Kali?

Comment: Complete 1TB available. No partitions at all

Answer (score 0):

I face similar problems whenever I install Parrot or Kali. Make sure you add `pcie_aspm=off` in your grub file and delete your log files completely.